# ¿Cómo replicar un trigger?

Tags: base-de-datos, mariadb

Tengo dos bases de datos:

1. Una con triggers que actualizan la información de la otra.

   > ejemplo: cuando inserto o actualizo un dato en mi base de datos "X"
   >   se dispara un trigger para que haga lo mismo en mi base de datos "Y".
2. He convertido a mi base de datos "Y" en maestra de una base de datos "Z"
   para que replique todo lo que se haga en "Y"

**El problema:** es que ninguno de los cambios realizados por los triggers en "Y" se ven reflejados en su esclava "Z".

**Pregunta:** ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que esto cambie y se vean reflejados los cambios provocados por los triggers disparados desde mi base de datos "X"?

**DBMS:**
10.1.13-MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

te cuento, esto lo he sacado de la [página oficial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

**Restricciones para disparadores**

Para los triggers, se aplican las siguientes restricciones adicionales:

- Los triggers no son activados por acciones clave externa.
- Cuando se utiliza la replicación basada en filas, los triggers en el
  esclavo no se activan por las declaraciones que se originan en el
  maestro. Los factores desencadenantes en el esclavo se activan cuando
  se utiliza la replicación basada en la declaración. Para obtener más
  información, consulte [Sección 18.4.1.35, "Replicación y disparadores"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-triggers.html)
  .
- El RETURN no está permitido en los triggers, ya que no
  pueden devolver un valor. Para salir de un trigger inmediato,
  utilice LEAVE.
- El caché del trigger no detecta cuando los metadatos de los objetos
  subyacentes han cambiado. Si un trigger utiliza una tabla y la
  tabla ha cambiado desde que el trigger se ha cargado en la memoria
  caché, el trigger funciona usando los metadatos obsoletos.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda, ésto afecta en la versión MySQL 5.7

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)[base-de-datos](/questions/tagged/base-de-datos)[maria-db](/questions/tagged/maria-db)

Comment: muy bien, checaré la pagina que mencionaste a ver si encuentro algo que me sirva.